# Get Keys and Value pair after removing an element from the key's list in a Map<List<String>, IInterface>

Tags: java, interface

In my use case, there is an interface IInterface and a map of List as keys and IInterface as values.

```
public interface IInterface{
   ....
}

public MyClass{
    Map<List<Integer>, IInterface> interfaceByStringList;
    MyClass(){
        interfaceByStringList = new HashMap<List<Integer>,IInterface>();
    }

    //Method to remove one element from key list
    public Map<List<Integer>, IInterface> myMethod(IntegerelementToRemove){
        ................
    }
}
```

In the above scenario, I have to remove "elementToRemove" from list of keys where it is present in the keySet() of the Map. Then I have to return the updated Map.

For e.g. 
Map's KeySet is like this:

```
{[1,2,3],[4,7,5],[67],[23,41]}
and corresponding values: 
{IInterface1, IInterface2,IInterface3,IInterface4]
```

Suppose if I want to remove 4 then my updated map to return:
Updated Map KeySet:

```
{[1,2,3],[7,5],[67],[23,41]}
and corresponding values: 
{IInterface1, IInterface2,IInterface3,IInterface4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take it:

```
interfaceByStringList
     .entrySet()
     .removeIf(entry -> entry.getKey().contains(elementToRemove));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
public Map<List<Integer>, IInterface> myMethod(int integerElementToRemove){
    interfaceByStringList
            .keySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(integers -> integers.contains(integerElementToRemove))
            .forEach(integers -> integers.remove(Integer.valueOf(integerElementToRemove)));
    return interfaceByStringList;
}
```